# I am unable to figure out why python version 2.7.16 in running, when version 3.7.7 is installed?

Tags: python, macos

`WARNING: Python 2.7 is not recommended. 
This version is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. 
Future versions of macOS will not include Python 2.7. 
Instead, it is recommended that you transition to using 'python3' from within Terminal.`

Python 2.7.16 (default, Feb 29 2020, 01:55:37) 
[GCC 4.2.`

`/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7: 4,006 files, 61.2MB
(base) Ashutoshs-Air:~ ashutoshrudraksh$ python --version
Python 2.7.16`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the current value of `$PATH` (the result of `echo "$PATH"`). Also fix up the text in your question. There is no indication of what commands produce that text for you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have both, try this

```
~> python --version
Python 2.7.17

~> python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
```

Besides, the fact that software has been installed in some /usr/local path does not neccesarily mean that it will be used - due to binary and library paths etc.

The first error message you pasted here recommends `that you transition to using 'python3' from within Terminal.`

Comment: is python3 is in use on my terminal?